# Calculate moments given density values

Tags: density, moments

Suppose I have given a finite number of grid values belonging to a probability density function. Moreover, I have the associated values of the density support. For instance:

```
support density value
0.06    0.07
-0.04   0.11
-0.02   0.52
0.00    1.56
0.02    7.87
0.04    19.18
0.06    13.66
0.08    3.40
0.10    0.98
0.13    0.33
0.15    0.14
0.17    0.07
0.19    0.00
0.22    0.43
0.24    0.01
```

Does anyone know the formula to calculate the first four moments of the distribution?

I would appreciate any help. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You could interpolate the density and then numerically integrate this function? You know, $E[X]=\int_\mathbb{R} xf_X(x)dx$ etc...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is:

$$ \mathbf{E}[X^k] = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^k p(x_i) $$

($X$ discrete variable, $x_i$ realizations, and $p(x_i)$ realization probabilities)

See [this link](https://medium.com/@praveenprashant/the-four-moments-of-a-probability-distribution-6b900a25d0d8) for further details.

Comment: Great, this helps a lot! thanks!

Comment: @Walter Glad to help. Unless you are waiting for other answers, please consider marking this answer as accepted (marking procedure available here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: As the densities do not yet sum to one, please also consider proper normalisation, no?

Comment: @Kermittfrog  Good point. If they don’t add up to one, one needs to normalize them. See, for example, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/278418/normalize-values-to-sum-1-but-keeping-their-weights

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, you did not mention which kind of momement. These calculated by formula in *ir7* are called general moments. However, there are also:

- Central moments defined as $E[X-EX]^k$
- Standardized moments defined as $E\big[\frac{X-EX}{\sigma(X)}\big]^k$,

where $EX$ is first general moment (expected value) and $\sigma(X)$ is second general moment (standard deviation).

Note that for $k=1$ the central moment and standardized moment are always 0. For $k=2$, the standardized moment is always 1.